# Splitting strings read from text file as a 2d array of characters

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I must use 2d arrays in my code and I am having a lot of trouble splitting the string in to a 1d array and storing it in a position in my 2d array `testCases[][]`. I am using the split function after I read in the string from the text file, to create an array of characters. Everything in my code below seems to make sense to me, however, when I try to iterate and print out the testCases array to ensure I collected the right data, it is printing out incorrect data.

I appreciate any help with figuring this one out, I have spent hours on this one problem.

Many thanks in advance.

```
//Read number of test cases 
String x = fin.nextLine();
int numTests = Integer.parseInt(x);

//create array
testCases = new String[numTests][100];

//Read actual test cases and store in 2d array
for(int i = 0; i < numTests; i++){
    String testCaseString = fin.nextLine();

    //System.out.println(testCaseString);                   
    testCases[i] = testCaseString.split("(?!^)"); 
    System.out.println(testCases[i][0]);
}
for(int z=0; z < numTests; z++){
    for(int q=0; q  < z; q++){
        System.out.printf("%s ", testCases[z][q]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Test Cases - Text file position

```
2
bcb
c
```

Current Console Output

```
c
```

Desired console Output

```
b c b
c
```

Comment: the line `for(int q=0; q  < z; q++)` has the effect, that you print 0 characters if z=0, 1 character if z=1, 2 characters if z=2 and so on. That `q<z` doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with *outputting the data*.

Try

```
for(int z=0; z < numTests; z++){
    for(int q=0; q  < testCases[z].length; q++){
        System.out.printf("%s ", testCases[z][q]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

In the inner loop you should iterate until `testCases[z].length`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you look at this section of code you will see that your loop is faulty.

```
for(int z=0; z < numTests; z++){
    for(int q=0; q  < z; q++){
        System.out.printf("%s ", testCases[z][q]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

q < z if q and z are both starting out at 0 then from the start q is not less than z, it is equal to z and when the loop completes and q is incremented it is now greater than z. Perhaps changing the inequality.